# kickstart five concurrent processes in bash

Tags: bash, mapreduce

I have a folder named `datafolder` which contains five csv files `aa.csv ab.csv ac.csv ad.csv ae.csv` Each csv file contains data from an excel sheet in the format: date, product type, name, address etc. and I am only interested in the second column which is named product. Basically what I want to happen is for the jobmaster script to count the number of files in `datafolder` and then to start a map process for each individual file. I have the following scripts:

The jobmaster script runs without problems, however once the map script starts, only the first `echo mapping $1` is displaying and the process is stuck in an infinite loop (my guess). When I run the `ps` command I expect to see 5 `map.sh` running, however there are none.

Comment: First, are you seeing all the echoes you would expect out of the jobmaster? If there are no map.sh running in ps they either finished running or were never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you missed an input redirection in `map.sh`:

```
file=$1
echo "mapping $file"
while IFS="," read -r value1 product remainder; do
    # ...
done < "$file"
#       ^^^^^ provide the standard input to from this file to `read`
```